# How can I forcefully select a text input through an onselect function?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm building a component to serve as an input for taking phone numbers which [you can see here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/2gHQwrqagGnbljo3bZmM?p=preview)

I'm using 3 text inputs to take each portion of the phone number and would like to use a function that controls which gets selected based on an if condition.  So for example lets say the user clicks on what's technically the 3rd input to go about entering their number.  I want it to automatically set the focus to the first input so they can start in the right place.

Here's my code so far.

template

```
<fieldset>
  <p class="input-container">
    (
    <input id="first" class="phnA" type="text"
      maxlength="3"
      pattern="^[0-9]{3}"
      placeholder ="123"
      [(ngModel)]="NumA"
      onselect="selection()"
    >
    )
    <input id="second" class="phnA" type="text"
      maxlength="3"
      pattern="^[0-9]{3}"
      placeholder ="456"
      [(ngModel)]="NumB"
      onselect="selection()"
    >
    -
    <input id="third" class="phnB" type="text"
      maxlength="4"
      pattern="^[0-9]{3}"
      placeholder ="7890"
      [(ngModel)]="NumC"
      onselect="selection()"
    >
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

function in component class

```
selection(){
    let a = document.getElementById('first');
    let b = document.getElementById('second');
    let c = document.getElementById('third');

    if( this.NumA.length > 3 ){
      document.getElementById("first").focus();
    }

    /*if(this.NumA.length < 3){
      a.focus();
    }else if(this.NumA.length = 3 && this.NumB.length < 3){
      b.focus();
    }else if(this.NumA.length = 3 && this.NumB.length = 3){
      c.focus();
    }*/
  }
```

My first attempt is the chunk that's commented out.  I tried applying it directly to see if maybe I was losing something through making it a variable and it still doesn't force the cursor into the first input.  The regexp I'm using to force numbers isn't working either.  the `NumA, NumB, NumC` variables are all set to be `string` because `maxlength` for some reason doesn't work on `type="number` inputs which is a different issue, jsut mentioning for the sake of explaining why they're not of `number` type.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Number wouldn't be a valid input type for what you're trying to do, anyway. These aren't really numbers that you're dealing with, they just happen to look like numbers. maxlength and pattern don't work with number because they aren't valid attributes for number. They only have an effect in a browser that doesn't support the number input type.

Comment: I would also remove the `^` from your pattern - it shouldn't be necessary. You may also just be able to use a single field, assuming you're okay with using `<input type="tel" />`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel#Pattern_validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through using part of Andresson's answer I came up with a solution. The parts I used are

- View Child implementation
- (focus) implementation on HTML elements

from there I created this function

```
selection(){
    let a = this.first;
    let b = this.second;
    let c = this.third;

    if(this.NumA.length < 1 && this.NumB.length < 1 && this.NumC.length < 1 && !event.keyCode)

    { a.nativeElement.focus(); }

    if(this.NumA.length > 2 && this.NumB.length < 1 && this.NumC.length < 1 && !event.keyCode)

    { b.nativeElement.focus(); }

    if(this.NumA.length > 2 && this.NumB.length > 2 && this.NumC.length < 1 && !event.keyCode)

    {c.nativeElement.focus();}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the "angular way"
First of drop the document.getelementbyID();
instead. add tags to your inputs: 
`#first #second #third` and modify your view. Notice the event trigger, we changed it to (focus) to fire the selection function.

```
<fieldset>
  <p class="input-container">
    <input #first class="phnA" type="text"
       maxlength="3"
       pattern="^[0-9]{3}"
       placeholder ="123"
       (focus)="selection(1)">
    <input #second class="phnA" type="text"
       maxlength="3"
       pattern="^[0-9]{3}"
       placeholder ="456"
       (focus)="selection(2)">
    <input #third class="phnB" type="text"
       maxlength="4"
       pattern="^[0-9]{3}"
       placeholder ="7890"
       (focus)="selection(3)">
```

Update your component and add @ViewChild() - This is a one way to interact with native DOM elements in angular.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('first') first: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('second') second: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('third') third: ElementRef;


  constructor(){
  }
  selection(inputNumber){

    if(inputNumber == 2) {
      if(this.first.nativeElement.value === "") {
        this.first.nativeElement.focus();
        return;
      }
    }
    if(inputNumber == 3) {
      if(this.first.nativeElement.value === "") {
        this.first.nativeElement.focus();
        return;
      }
      if(this.second.nativeElement.value === "") {
        this.second.nativeElement.focus();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helped, More information about how @ViewChild() can be found [here.](http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/)

Comment: I was just looking into some of the things you mentioned and I think they might help.  I would like to know if the `(focus)` part you added in is an actual method or property withing angular or is it simething you jsut made up?  I saw something similar done with `@Output` where you can set your event emitter that way.  Also why did you change the if conditions to check if they're empty?  I was saying `>3` because say they had 2 digits of their area code in `first` and they selected on one of the other boxes for some reason, this code would allow them because `first` isn't empty.

Comment: Plus this checks for if the field has a value, not how many digits the value has, which is why I was trying to use `.length`.  Other than that I'm going to try to the other stuff and continue messing with it.

Comment: also why did you take away the `ngModel`?

Comment: First, the (focus) part is not something i made up. In angular HTML DOM component's events are just like the normal events but instead of using onfocus, or onblur etc. you remove the "on" prefix. 
Second, Im sorry to confuse you, your logic in selcection() function is probably completely valid.. the reason I changed it was to test it out for my self, which also answers why i took away the ngModel, because i was not sure why you where using `NumA...` But now I understand why.